why does linqpad serialization ignore the midnight in visual representation
I have this hourly data. it shows up properly formatted for all the rows except the ones with midnight
code is uploaded at
https://share.linqpad.net/429vqowu.linq

look at the midnight and notice how it does not show the 00:00:00
void Main()
{
    // Generate hourly DateTime data for 2 days
    var startDate = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc); // Example start date
    var endDate = startDate.AddDays(2);
    var hourlyDates = new List<DateTime>();

    for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddHours(1))
    {
        hourlyDates.Add(date);
    }

    // Serialize the list to JSON
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hourlyDates);

    // Deserialize the JSON back to a list of DateTime objects
    var deserializedDates = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DateTime>>(json);

    // Dump the deserialized data to LinqPad
    deserializedDates.Dump();
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here


What is the culture set on your machine?

This seems to be an artifact of whatever the Dump() debugging extension method does on LINQPad.  The dotnetfiddle equivalent doesn't even seem to show the times.  But regardless, the JSON generated by Newtonsoft should be correct.  On dotnetfiddle it shows "2024-01-02T00:00:00Z", and round-trips without any data loss, and Assert.That(hourlyDates.SequenceEqual(deserializedDates!)); also passes successfully.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/NtNEJt.  Can you check to see whether LINQPad generates the same JSON as dotnetfiddle?

no repro on 8.6.6 and latest 5.51.02 version...

i have
Environment version: .NET 7.0.11 (7.0.11), Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.22621.0
Newtonsoft.Json version: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
and when i print out the json value persisted, i can see   "2024-01-01T00:00:00Z",
But when i expose it on the grid using linqpad, it does not show the midnight  hour and minutes.
When i switch to rich text in linqpad, i can see the 2024-01-01 12:00:00 AM

@junkone Sounds like an obscure 7x bug. I really recommend upgrading to 8x. Very satisfied with it (not sure if benchmarking came with it)

Remember that DateTime objects are not strings.  How they appear in string format can differ.  If you want a specific string representation, you should convert it to a string before you add it to a List (a list of strings).

@IvanPetrov This only happens when outputting to DataGrids rather than Rich Text (Html) and happens with hourlyDates so isn't related to serialization.

If you don't like this behaviour then with LINQPad 8.4 and later you can set your own custom format, for example
DumpOptions.Default.FormatStrings.DateTime = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt";

This isn't actually related to serialization as the same thing happens if you dump your source hourlyDates and only happens if you dump to DataGrids rather than the default Rich Text(Html).
What I think is happening is that LinqPad is simply detecting whether the value has a time component and using a different format in that case.
